# Encode email with PHP then decode with JS

Tags: php, javascript, email, decode, encode

I'm working on a website that has many business profiles with their contact information which also include email addresses. Obviously I don't want to output the plain email addresses in the source due to spam. Could do mrsmith[at]gmail.com or [obfuscate with ASCII](http://www.roytanck.com/2009/02/18/obfuscate-email-addresses-using-php/) but these solutions aren't ideal, not 100% foolproof.

The profiles do have a contact form but I also need to show the email addresses.

What I want to do is encode the emails with PHP and then decode with JS and create the anchor link dynamically. So I need an algorithm that's the same in PHP an JS if there is any...

Comment: Why is there a need to display an obfuscated address?

Comment: I've rephrased my question slightly, should be clearer now

Comment: I'll try and rephrase my question then: If the mail address shown is obfuscated what good is it?

Comment: Another option would be using images. That will also work in browsers with Javascript disabled.

Comment: If you're going to **show** the email address, you have to show it. Ordinary people don't understand anti-spam obfuscation methods; only people like us do. If your server is going to handle sending mail, then there's no need to show the email address at all.

Comment: It will only be obfuscated in the source, I want to de-obfuscate it with JS and create a mailto: link dynamically so people can click on it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn images can be read with OCR tools.

Comment: What's the point of obfuscating the email address in the source? If you're going to create a "mailto:" link anyway, the spammers can always get the modified state of the page, so that would do you no good at all.

Comment: @Pointy are you saying that spambots can read the DOM?

Comment: @Pointy, spambots can take a screenshot of a website, and no matter what advanced obfuscation you use for email, they'll get it anyway. You have to weight user-friendliness against safety. You can use ten keys for your car, but it's easier to have one for operation.

Comment: @Temega **of course** they can - there are server-side solutions involving using an actual browser to render pages. If you put it on a web page, a spammer will get it. @Lekensteyn yes that's exactly the point I was making.

Comment: @Pointy wow, didn't know that! How common are such smart bots compared to regular source scanning bots?

Comment: I'm not sure how common they are, but if you really want to protect your email addresses I wouldn't rely on them being rare :-)

Comment: @Pointy, it's like the joke about running from a bear. If your email addresses are hard to get, spammers won't bother - the web is full of easier targets. Unless you are someone really big, using anything that cannot be decoded off-the-shelf or within a few lines makes you safe IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now solved this with a form asking the user to fill in a value and submit it. If value i correct, show email address. Also set an 'isHuman' session parameter so others emails will just show by default.

Answer (score 1):

First, use SSL.  Then use an AJAX request to get the Data (jQuery will help with the AJAX).  Seperate it into two requests.  ex for yummyfood@mybusiness.com:

One request that gives yummyfood.

Then have another request that gives mybusiness.com.

The last idea is to use [recaptcha mailhide (by Google)](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/).  It will secure your email addressed just fine if that is the approach you want to take.

Comment: I rather just do something like "Are you human? type in 'yes'" than captcha, captcha is so user unfriendly...